# Solidity, Wrapping Eth from a contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, hardhat, erc20

I'm trying to wrap Eth from an smart contract as I want to swap weth later in uniswap but I don't know how to import the WETH code from goerli scan `WETH = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6;`.
Following internet examples I accomplished wrapping Eth but all influencers just import a ERC20 library to create a new one. I don't understand why they are using this as they are not interacting with the right weth contract.

Here is the code I used but is just creating a new token. Can anyone give me some advice?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';


contract SwapExamples is ERC20 {
    // For the scope of these swap examples,
    // we will detail the design considerations when using `exactInput`, `exactInputSingle`, `exactOutput`, and  `exactOutputSingle`.
    // It should be noted that for the sake of these examples we pass in the swap router as a constructor argument instead of inheriting it.
    // More advanced example contracts will detail how to inherit the swap router safely.
    // This example swaps DAI/WETH9 for single path swaps and DAI/USDC/WETH9 for multi path swaps.

    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;
    address payable [] private s_Wallets;
    uint256 public walletA = address(this).balance;

    // Router = 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564

    address public constant WETH = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6; //0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;


    // For this example, we will set the pool fee to 0.3%.
    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;
    uint256 public UsdOut;

    constructor(ISwapRouter _swapRouter) ERC20("Wrapped Ether", "WETH") {//ERC20("Wrapped Ether", "WETH") 
        swapRouter = _swapRouter;
    }
    function Deposit() public payable {

        s_Wallets.push(payable(msg.sender));
            
    } 

    function Mint() external payable {
        _mint(address(this), address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not create a new ERC20 token.

Calling:
`WETH.deposit.value(msg.value)();`
helps you wrap your ETH and you don't need to import WETH code from anywhere.

After wrapping, you can then move on to swapping WETH for any other token on Uniswap like you said.

Comment: I don't understand why do I need to create a new ERC20 token. I solved the code importing the interface of the weth contract (goerlic testnet) weth = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6. 
If I create  a new ERC20 how am I going to interact with the weth with the contract above?

I guess using this WETH.deposit.value(msg.value)(); I need somthing else to be imported, Could you clarify this?
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Also I did a swap on uniswapV3 with weth previously wrapped and the exchange was 0.005weth = 173.68 DAI Is this normal?

This is the tx: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x92f4d746b89f65a50e49657fb1fbe0a1d1446c1881210beac56ff5e9a7d90567

Comment: Solved the second problem, looks that is not a stable DAI. It just have a different price.